# to replace if a position has one string else if its a different string replace with another

Tags: unix

Hi I have got a file that looks like below and I need to check if the 3rd position is W then replace it with A else if it is M replace it with X in unix . Can anyone help?

Input file:

CRM~ABC~M~124

CRM~CDF~W~875

Output expected :

CRM~ABC~X~124

CRM~CDF~A~875

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

With awk this is done easily, taking care of having the tilde both as input field separator (FS) and as output field separator (OFS). You then just replace the third field according to your needs:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="~"} $3=="M" {$3="X"} $3=="W" {$3="A"} {print}' yourfile
```

The sed answer is longer:

```
sed 's/\(^[^~]*~[^~]*~\)M~/\1X~/;s/\(^[^~]*~[^~]*~\)W~/\1A~/' yourfile
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Er, sorry, personally I am not criticizing nor requesting a clarification from the author of the question. I do respect your own right to do so, though, as well as Nathan Cooper's right to do so. I simply believe my answer can be useful to the user who asked it... So my answer is not addressing Nathan's question, because only the author of the original question can answer that one :)

Comment: Your question was flagged as a short answer.. posting the code or the command without even explaining what's happening deserves it I think. I'm sorry too :) btw this was before you even edited the answer.

Comment: Hi Hatem, a bit of misunderstanding here from your side, maybe: I am not "user3853065" nor "miku", so I didn't ask the question initially. The question (and not my answer) has been downvoted, probably because somebody thought is was unclear or not showing any research effort, which is maybe true. I just provided an answer that I've just made more verbose thanks to your last comment.